# add navigation buttons Fotorama 4.4.9 API

Tags: api, image-gallery, photo-gallery, fotorama

I am using the new Fotorama script 4.4.9 and I am new to use API.

I am trying to add custom navigation buttons to the slideshow (stop, pause, previous and next) but I dont know how to implement it using API.

I have been looking at the official page http://fotorama.io/customize/api/
 but I cannot get it to work...

Can someone please provide a sample of API custom navigation buttons on the new Fotorama 4?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22564811%22answer%22) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22564811) there i add a customs buttons next and back there is a example how to use the API