# Using different data-attribute values for different resolutions in the fotorama plugin

Tags: jquery, fotorama

I am looking for a way to change the data-attributes according to the resolution, for example, use a smaller data-min-height for smaller resolutions.

How can this be achieved? Thanks for your time!

Comment: can you share the code and approach you have tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything! I have no idea how to accomplish this! :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.data()` along with `$(document).height()` or `$(window).height()`:

```
 $('selector').data('min-height',$(document).height());
```

Comment: @scooterlord:what is the problem??

Comment: I currently have the fotorama set with inline data-min-height="400" and want to have this changed to 200 if res is smaller than 480px. I put it inside a window resize event, but have no luck with it :/

Comment: Just noticed there's a resize method, but still have no idea how it works. :/

Comment: @scooterlord: can you create a fiddle. we will work rest on it.

Comment: Found the solution.. you had to create vars before using the api: var $fotoramaDiv = $('.fotorama').fotorama();
var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');

Answer (score 1):

try with this function [setOptions](http://fotorama.io/customize/api/#fotorama.setOptions%28options%29)

```
fotorama.setOptions({
  nav: false,
  arrows: false
});
```

Here you can see a example how use the api [Move fotorama arrows outside stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448298/move-fotorama-arrows-outside-stage/22564811#22564811)